# Im getting a "EOL while scanning string literal" while doing beginners coding, idk what else to do

Tags: python, notepad++

i'm a beginner at coding and I've spent hours trying to fix this, I don't know what else to do

this is the code

```
import time
Sid = input("yes hi my name bub, what ur name?")
if (Sid != "bob MC cool pants"):
    print ("i don't care...)                               
time.sleep(2)
print ("so how are the kids???")
```

it highlights the empty space after the ("I don't care..."), I dont know why it didn't do this in any of the other tests I'm testing please help

Comment: Change `print ("i don't care...)` to `print ("i don't care...")`.

Comment: you're missing a `"` at the end of your string

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @Aran-Fey

```
import time
Sid = input("yes hi my name bub, what ur name?")
if (Sid != "bob MC cool pants"):
    print ("i don't care...")                               
time.sleep(2)
print ("so how are the kids???")
```

You forgot to close off the string - which is a variable type that is designed to store characters. In Python, when writing the value of a string, you put **" "** marks around it,  telling the python interpreter that what you have typed is in fact a string.

Since you forgot to add an ending **"** the python interpreter thought that the closing parenthesis **)** was actually part of the string. The error is basically python saying *"Hey, there's an open parenthesis, but where is the closing one?"*